# How to force / conditional join completely unrelated cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have been scratching my head on this one and getting nowhere so where it goes. Having two tables like below how can I join a completely unrelated cell to another. My data is not ISO standardized and cannot figure out a way to join Scotland to United Kingdom of Great Britain.

SQL SERVER 2016

tb1

```
id    Country_ISO
1     United Kingdom of Great Britain
2     Oman
```

tb2

```
id    Country
1     United kingdom
2     Scotland
3     Oman
```

Result

```
id    Country           ID    Country_ISO
1     United kingdom    1     United Kingdom of Great Britain
2     Scotland          1     United Kingdom of Great Britain
3     Oman              2     Oman
```

Comment: You'll need to decide on the strategy to join the rows, not us. The database cannot magically guess those values represent the same kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement in the `join`

```
select *
from tb2 
left join tb1 on tb1.country_iso=case when tb2.country in ('United Kingdom','Scotland')
                                      then 'United Kingdom of Great Britain' 
                                      else tb2.country end;
```

**Outputs**

```
+----+----------------+----+---------------------------------+
| id |    country     | id |           country_iso           |
+----+----------------+----+---------------------------------+
|  1 | United Kingdom |  1 | United Kingdom of Great Britain |
|  2 | Scotland       |  1 | United Kingdom of Great Britain |
|  3 | Oman           |  2 | Oman                            |
+----+----------------+----+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another row to country_iso:

```
select tb2.*, tb1.id, tb1.country
from tb2 left join
     (select id, country as match_country, country
      from tb1
      union all
      select tb1.id, 'Scotland', tb1.country
      from tb1
      where tb1.id = 1
     ) tb1
     on tb1.country = tb2.match_country;
```

The subquery suggests, perhaps, a new table for your database to simplify these transformations.

Alternatively, you could use a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select tb2.*,
       (case when tb2.country = 'Scotland' then 1 else tb1.id end),
       (case when tb2.country = 'Scotland' then 'United Kingdom of Great Britain' else tb1.country end)
from tb2 left join
     tb1
     on tb1.country = tb2.country;
```

The advantage of this approach is that the query can make use of indexes and should be fast.